# Angularjs: inject Controller on module inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a bit newbiew with `javascript` and i am starting to use `angular.js`

So my question is if there is a way to inject a controller inside a module that is declared in an anonymous function

my code looks like this

**app.js**

```
(function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('Organizer', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria']);
})(angular);
```

**siteController.js**

```
(function(angular, app) {
    app.controller('site', function($scope, $mdDialog)
    {
        var alert = $mdDialog.alert({
            title: 'Test',
            content: 'Testing',
            ok: 'Exit'
        });

        $mdDialog.show(alert);
    });
})(angular);
```

i have tried to look for ways if it is possible, but still i would like to see if anyone here could explain how this can be made if it could.

**Note:** I have already used `angular.js` before and i wanted to try a different way to declare controllers so the client wont have any way to modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a module in Angular, then you can not obfuscate it in this way. In the console, a user can just run `angular.module('Organizer')` to get access to your app, and then call any method they want on it.

The reason your code won't work as written, is because you are not passing the `app` variable to your anonymous function. So if you want to add a controller to the `Organizer` module, then you would do something like this:

```
(function(angular)
{
    angular.
      module('Organizer').
      controller('site', function($scope, $mdDialog)
      {
          ...
      });
})(angular);
```

Comment: well, thanks for the explanation, i will mark this as the solution

Answer (score 1):

Theres no need to wrap any of this code in self executing functions as if you are trying to keep variables out of the global scope.  The only one that's global is the "angular" object.

Your app.js should only have

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Organizer', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria']);
```

You controller file should only have

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Organizer').controller('siteController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
    var alert = $mdDialog.alert({
        title: 'Test',
        content: 'Testing',
        ok: 'Exit'
    });

    $mdDialog.show(alert);
});
```

The first call to module in app.js passes the second parameter which angular uses to instantiate your module.  Subsequent calls that omit the second parameter "get" the module.

Comment: this is also a solution but i am already coding in the other way

Comment: @nosthertus Its not "also a solution"  Its the standard way to do things in angularjs.